# JProgressBar is invisible but progress is updating correctly

Tags: java, swing, swingworker, jprogressbar, invisible

I execute the task in this class and the Dialog pops up as a white box. The print statement IS printing out the progress values I'm expecting, but nothing shows up on the Dialog until after the operation is complete. I can see the progress bar flash visible for a millisecond before the dialog is closed at the end. Absolutely no clue what's going on :\

```
    public class ProgressDialog extends JDialog {

    private JProgressBar pb;
    private SwingWorker<Boolean, Void> task;

    public SwingWorker<Boolean, Void> getTask(){
        return task;
    }

    public ProgressDialog(final String call){
        setTitle("Working...");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setBounds(300,300,300,100);
        pb = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
        pb.setValue(0);
        pb.setVisible(true);
        pb.setStringPainted(true);
        add(pb, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setVisible(true);

        task = new SwingWorker<Boolean, Void>(){
            public Boolean doInBackground(){        
                switch(call){
                case "Category": pb.setValue(Category.getProgress());
                while(pb.getValue()<99){
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e){
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                    pb.setValue(Category.getProgress());
                    System.out.println(pb.getValue());
                    repaint();
                    revalidate();
                }
                break;
                }
                return true;
            }
            public void done(){
                dispose();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

EDIT: tried this change. no dice. Why am I not even getting a progress bar at 0%? It only appears once it is at 100%

```
public class ProgressDialog extends JDialog {

private JProgressBar pb;
private SwingWorker<Boolean, Integer> task;

public SwingWorker<Boolean, Integer> getTask(){
    return task;
}

public ProgressDialog(final String call){
    setTitle("Working...");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setBounds(300,300,300,100);
    pb = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
    pb.setValue(0);
    pb.setStringPainted(true);
    add(pb, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setVisible(true);

    task = new SwingWorker<Boolean, Integer>(){
        public Boolean doInBackground(){        
            switch(call){
            case "Category": setProgress(Category.getProgress());
            while(pb.getValue()<99){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                setProgress(Category.getProgress());
            }
            break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public void done(){
            //dispose();
        }
    };

    task.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                public  void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                    if ("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                        System.out.println((Integer)evt.getNewValue());
                        pb.setValue((Integer)evt.getNewValue());
                        pb.revalidate();
                        pb.repaint();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

}

Comment: Please look at updates to answers, in particular, ryvantage's answer and code, which you should probably accept.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to set the progress bar's state from within the SwingWorker's doInBackground method, from a **background thread** -- which makes no sense. The whole reason for using a SwingWorker is to allow you to do a background process in a Swing GUI, so you don't make Swing calls from a background thread, and so that you don't tie up the Swing thread with a long-running bit of code.

You should not make Swing calls from this background process. Instead use the publish/process methods as the tutorials will show you. Or perhaps better, set the SwingWorker's progress field, and use a PropertyChangeListener on the SwingWorker to allow the progress bar to react to it.

Regardless, the bottom line:

- Use the SwingWorker to do background work.
- Do not make Swing calls from within the SwingWorker's doInBackground method.
- Use publish to push data from the background method into the Swing thread realm.
- Use the process method to handle this data being pushed.
- SwingWorker has a progress property that is also handy to use for allowing Swing code to respond to changes in background states.
- If you go this route, use a PropertyChangeListener.
- You almost **never** want to use `setBounds(...)` or null layout. Trust me as someone who has written hundreds of Swing programs, this one will bite you in the end.
- It looks as if your Category is using a **static** method for getting its progress. Again, this is something you almost never want to do. A progress field suggests *state*, and this should be part of the instance fields of an object, never static.

Comment: I tried both suggestions and they both resulted in the progressbar only receiving one update once it reached 100. I'm even more confused than I started

Comment: @MichaelGroleau: if you've made changes, please post the code as an edit to your original question. Don't change the code and text of the original question, but add the new information to the bottom.

Comment: @MichaelGroleau: then you'll need to create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org). Hang on, I'll show you an example of what I mean.

Comment: @MichaelGroleau: note also that if your JDialog is modal, then all pertinent code must be called before setting the dialog visible.

Comment: @MichaelGroleau: no time to do it. Going to bed.

Comment: @MichaelGroleau, it may be confusing but you MUST learn to use `SwingWorker` correctly. Once you -get it- you'll rejoice because it makes so much sense and your code will run fine. Don't kick against the pricks.

Comment: The essence of SwingWorker: DO NOT call `Swing` code on a background thread and DO NOT call time-consuming code on the EDT. YOU MUST call time-consuming code on the background thread and YOU MUST call `Swing` code on the EDT. `doInBackground()` is always on the background thread, `done()` and `process()` is always on the EDT.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an SSCCE to demonstrate how you should be updating your `JProgressBar`. Copy/paste this and run it.

Notice how we update the progress bar by calling `publish(i)` which sends the integer to the `process()` method. The `SwingWorker` sends results to the `process()` method in chunks, but we are only using an `Integer` to update the `JProgressBar` so all we care about it the LAST chunk. In this SSCCE, we go from 1-1000. If you examine the console, you'll see that a lot of numbers between 1-1000 are being skipped because we are updating too fast for the `SwingWorker` to catch up (but that's ok. That's why it delivers results in chunks).

NOTE: the `process()` method was originally designed for programmers to return real-time results from their long-running processes and update the GUI. So, if you were doing a database fetch, you could update a `JTable` with the results you return. I hate doing things that way, though. So 99% of the time I just use an "indeterminate" `JProgressBar` and wait till the `done()` method to publish my results. Occaisionally, however, I'll use a "determinate" `JProgressBar` and update like we do in this SSCCE. Never have I used `process()` to return and publish actual data. :) But, that's what it was originally designed to do.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

/**
 *
 * @author Ryan
 */
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                go();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void go() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JProgressBar jpb = new JProgressBar();
        jpb.setIndeterminate(false);
        int max = 1000;
        jpb.setMaximum(max);
        frame.add(jpb);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        new Task(jpb, max).execute();
    }

    static class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer> {

        JProgressBar jpb;
        int max;
        public Task(JProgressBar jpb, int max) {
            this.jpb = jpb;
            this.max = max;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
            jpb.setValue(chunks.get(chunks.size()-1)); // The last value in this array is all we care about.
            System.out.println(chunks.get(chunks.size()-1));
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(10); // Sleep for 1/10th of a second
                publish(i);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            try {
                get();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jpb.getParent(), "Success", "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I created a diagram that should be a helpful reference when handling `SwingWorker` so you know where to place your code.

[image]

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, what'd you think of the diagram? Useful?